# Error Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string' in className when I use map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have an error in `className` in **typeScript**. Type of items is string and map function return a string type. How can I solve it?

```
<section
    className={ //problem here
        ActiveclassName.map((item: string) => {
            return item;
        }) || ''
    }
>
    <FoodBadge quantity={newItem.quantity} />
    {renderImage}
    <FoodDetails food={newItem} />

    {showModal ? (
        <Portal>
            <Modal show={showModal} onClose={handleshowModal}>
                <DetailModal defaultDetail={food} food={newItem} />
            </Modal>
        </Portal>
    ) : null}
</section>
```

Comment: map returns an array, you can call `.join(' ')` on the array to return a string if you have multiple classes inside the  array `ActiveclassName.join(' ')`

Comment: `.map` returns an array, not a string. Moreover, your `.map` function does nothing - it returns the same thing as what it gets, so `ActiveclassName.map((item: string) => { return item; })` only makes a copy of the `ActieclassName` array.